# How to clear all anchor styling from @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

In my MVC application, I have used `@Html.ActionLink`. I have set their styles to display them like a button, but the problem is that there are stome styles for `a, a:link`, etc (I mean, all anchor behaviors) in the CSS file, and that is why the links on `@Html.ActionLink` appears like links, and not plain text. Any idea to get rid of all anchor behavior for those particular `@Html.Actionlink` controls?

Comment: `@Html.Actionlink` renderes just plain HTML anchor tag. So I think you could achieve your task by playing with CSS styles. There is also overload of `@Html.ActionLink` where you can set html attributes like style and class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is using jQuery an option? You could write a function to remove the css from each link on startup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // to clear css from a specific item
    $("#your-link-id").removeClass();

    // to clear css from a bunch of links
    $("your-selector a").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
});
```

Or you could create additional css classes that override the styles on your `a` tags.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .whatever { background-color:black !important; }
</style>
```

`@Html.ActionLink("MyAction", "MyController", new { @class = "whatever" })`